# How to add trigram index with lower function in rails 5

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

To use a trigram index, I need to write like this.

```
add_index :people, :last_name, using: :gist, opclass: { last_name: :gist_trgm_ops }
```

And I want to use it wiht `LOWER` function.

```
add_index :people, "lower(last_name)", using: :gist, opclass: { "lower(last_name)" => :gist_trgm_ops }
```

I can run this migration but it seems the index is not created properly.
With `execute` command I could create the proper index.

```
execute "CREATE INDEX index_people_on_lower_last_name ON people USING GIST (lower(last_name) gist_trgm_ops);"
```

As far as posibble I want to avoid using `execute`. Is there a better way to write migration file for trigram index with postgres function?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  All the operations supported by trigram indexes have case insensitive variants.  Just use them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that is case sensitive.

Comment: You get your choice.  LIKE is case sensitive, ILIKE is not.  `~` is case sensitive, `~*` is not.  There is no case sensitive variant of `<->`, so you don't always have a choice, but where you don't it is in the direction you want.